# Call a certain URL on HTML5 upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

Alright, So I have this script that uploads a file on drag and drop from the browser using HTML5.

```
$(function(){

var dropbox = $('#dropbox'),
    message = $('.message', dropbox);

dropbox.filedrop({
    // The name of the $_FILES entry:
    paramname:'pic',

    maxfiles: 50,
    maxfilesize: 50,
    url: 'post_file.php',

    uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
        $.data(file).addClass('done');
        // response is the JSON object that post_file.php returns
    },

    error: function(err, file) {
        switch(err) {
            case 'BrowserNotSupported':
                showMessage('Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
                break;
            case 'TooManyFiles':
                alert('Too many files! Please select 20 at most! (configurable)');
                break;
            case 'FileTooLarge':
                alert(file.name+' is too large! Please upload files up to 10mb (configurable).');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    },

    //// Called before each upload is started
//      beforeEach: function(file){
//          if(!file.type.match(/^image\//)){
//              alert('Only images are allowed!');
//              
//              // Returning false will cause the
//              // file to be rejected
//              return false;
//          }
//      },

    uploadStarted:function(i, file, len){
        createImage(file);
    },

    progressUpdated: function(i, file, progress) {
        $.data(file).find('.progress').width(progress);
    }

});

var template = '<div class="preview">'+
                    '<span class="imageHolder">'+
                        '<img />'+
                        '<span class="uploaded"></span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '<div class="progressHolder">'+
                        '<div class="progress"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'; 


function createImage(file){

    var preview = $(template), 
        image = $('img', preview);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    image.width = 100;
    image.height = 100;

    reader.onload = function(e){

        // e.target.result holds the DataURL which
        // can be used as a source of the image:

        image.attr('src',e.target.result);
    };

    // Reading the file as a DataURL. When finished,
    // this will trigger the onload function above:
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    message.hide();
    preview.appendTo(dropbox);

    // Associating a preview container
    // with the file, using jQuery's $.data():

    $.data(file,preview);
}

function showMessage(msg){
    message.html(msg);
}

});
```

It runs on with the following post_file.php

```
<?php

// If you want to ignore the uploaded files, 
// set $demo_mode to true;

$demo_mode = false;
$upload_dir = 'uploads/';
//$allowed_ext =     array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','doc','docx','pdf','xls','xlsx','pptx','ppt','rtf','txt','mp4','css','rar','zip','exe','mp3','wav');


if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}


if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

$pic = $_FILES['pic'];

//if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
//  exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
//} 

if($demo_mode){

    // File uploads are ignored. We only log them.

    $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
    file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

    exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
}


// Move the uploaded file from the temporary 
// directory to the uploads folder:

if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){
    exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');
}
}

exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');


// Helper functions

function exit_status($str){
echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
exit;
}

function get_extension($file_name){
$ext = explode('.', $file_name);
$ext = array_pop($ext);
return strtolower($ext);
}
?>
```

Now the problem is I have a certain JSON url that when I open it sends a text message to a certain number. I'm trying to append that URL somewhere in the script so that it runs that url everytime an upload is made.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could either redirect to that URL after processing the upload (if you want it’s result to be shown client side), or make a request to it from within your PHP script.

Comment: Yeah I think I wanna go with the latter one. I don't want the result to show to the end user. But the question is how to request it from within the PHP?

Comment: Don’t tell me your prior research on that did come up with absolutely nothing …?

Comment: $payload = file_get_contents('http://api.someservice.com/SomeMethod?param=value');

Comment: I think that might work, but my problem is where to put that within the script so that it runs when the upload is complete.

Comment: Mayby in about the same place where you output a message _saying_ that the file was uploaded successfully …?

Answer (score 0):

$URL = "http://www.api.com/api.php?data=mydata";
$data = file_get_contents($URL);

This solves it.